# Can't set controller's content when async action in EmberJS

Tags: ember.js

I'm getting stuck when I want to update my controller's content after a specific action :

this.set('content', CL.myModel.findALL());

I'm not using ember-data or any of them.

CL.myModel.findALL returns an Ember promise that returns itself the result in it's callback.

Actually, I've done the same thing in my setupController in the router and It works well.
Why does it not work in the controller itself ?

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 1):

You should do:

```
controller = this;

CL.myModle.findALL().then(function(models) {
  controller.set('content', models);      
})
```

I believe the reason that it works without this in `Route#setupController` is because, behind the scenes, Ember does something similar to the above code with the result of your `model` hook (which is typically a promise).

Another option you could look at is [DS.PromiseObject](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.PromiseObject.html) (it's a nice abstraction for promises that wrap a promise and expose it's fulfillment value as `content`. You'd have to extract it from an ember-data build though.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, I also think about this solution but in the resolver of my CL.myModle.findALL() promise I need to work on the data, I cannot display immediatly the datas from the web service. There is no way to set the content by getting a promise ?

Comment: I'm sorry - I'm a bit confused by your comment. Your question mentioned that `CL.myModle.findALL()` returns a promise, so the code in my answer is doing is *only* setting your controller's content once the promise has resolved (meaning the data is available).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of my model :

```
CL.myModle.reopenClass({
   findAll : function(){
        return CL.Utils.ajaxPromise(r)
        .then(this.findByIdSuccess.bind(this), this.findByIdFailed.bind(this));
   },
   findByIdSuccess: function (data) {
       var negotiation = CL.NegotiationModel.create(data);
       this.setMembers(negotiation);
       this.setParties(negotiation);
       this.setVersions(negotiation);

       return negotiation;
   },
})
```

Here is my controller :

```
onRefresh : function(){
    this.set('content',CL.myModle.findAll())
}
```

As you can see in the model part I call some functions that do some model modification and I get it back findByIdSuccess callback.

I can't just return the datas I retrieve in the "then" of the promise.

My question again if it's still not clear : Is there any way to get the promise's data without doing :

```
CL.myModle.findALL().then(function(models) {
   controller.set('content', models);      
})
```